# Android Studio gradle apk and run out of sync

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio and I have the following build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName "1.0"
        versionCode 2
        versionNameSuffix = ".alpha1"
        def date = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
        if (versionNameSuffix.equals("")) {
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "myapp.$versionName.$versionCode")
        } else {
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", "myapp.$versionName.$versionCode$versionNameSuffix." + date)
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_DEBUG', 'false'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'BUILD_DATE', '\"' + date + '\"'
        buildConfigField 'String', 'VERSION_STRING', '\"' + "$versionName.$versionCode$versionNameSuffix" + '\"'
        resValue "string", "BUILD_DATE", date
        resValue "string", "VERSION", "$versionName.$versionCode$versionNameSuffix"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_DEBUG', 'false'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("-release", "")
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_DEBUG', 'true'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Basically when I Build->Rebuild Project or Build->Build APK, I generate an apk file like myapp.1.0.2.alpha1.20170224125933.apk

The last bit on the end is a time-stamp. (20170224125933 => 2017/2/24 12:59:33)

Everything works perfectly when running manually via the apk.

The issue I am having is that when I try to Run->Run myapp through Android Studio, it seems to always look for an earilier time-stamp.

For example, let's say I Rebuild Project and get the file: myapp.1.0.2.alpha1.20170224125933.apk.  I make some code changes and want to Run it through Anroid Studio.  When I go to Run, it rebuilds the project again (generating myapp.1.0.2.alpha1.20170224130417.apk) and deletes the previous file (myapp.1.0.2.alpha1.20170224125933.apk) as expected, but, tries to install the previous file.  I then get an "error while installing apk.  File myapp.1.0.2.alpha1.20170224125933.apk not found."

The only solution I've found is to drop the seconds marker (change the Date format to 'yyyyMMddHHmm'), click Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files, then immediately hit Run.  This usually works unless the clock changes minutes during the few seconds this process takes.

I'm thinking I need a Gradle->Task Activitaion or something so that when I click Run, it generates a new apk, and knows to use the recently generated one.

Any ideas?

Comment: that thread is about renaming the apk file, and mine is working exactly as expected in that regard.  My issue is that when I try to "Run->Run myapp" through android studio, it can't find the newly generated apk file (looks instead for an older time-stamped on for some reason).